# what is the impact over Collection implementations when hashcode() returns zero

Tags: java, collections, hashcode

Ok just for knowledge , what significance it would made on Collection implementation classes like `hashmap`,`hashset` etc if the `object's` `hashcode` method always returns `0` in a `demoClass`. I know it has something to do with `putForNullKey` of hashmap or other classes of Collection implementation, but dont know much in details. I know for null objects the hascode is `0` so it has specfic method for 0 hashcode.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will make `HashMap`, `HashSet` and other collections that rely on `hashCode` very inefficient, since all elements/entries would be added to the same bin.

Methods such as `get()`, `containsKey()` and `contains()` would take `O(n)` instead of `O(1)`.

BTW, the answer is not specific to a 0 `hashCode`. Any constant `hashCode` would behave exactly the same.

Comment: what about other structures like `Set` ?

Comment: @BhargavModi I mentioned HashSet. Not all Set implementation use hashCode.