# Why hashcode method of String class is called internally even if i override hashcode method

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

```
import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class TestClass {
     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      return false;
     }

     @Override
     public int hashCode() {
      return 1;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
      HashMap<TestClass, Integer> hm = new HashMap<TestClass, Integer>();
      hm.put(new TestClass(), 1);
      hm.put(new TestClass(), 2);
      hm.put(new TestClass(), 3);

     for (Map.Entry<TestClass, Integer> m : hm.entrySet()) {
       System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + m.getValue());
      }

     }

    }
```

I am overriding hashcode in my TestClass,but while debugging i found that it is calling String's hashcode method instead of calling my overridden method

Comment: String is a final class. You can not override String's hashcode method

Comment: On which line you got the call at debugging?

Comment: You are overriding `Object class's hashCode` method , not String class !!

Comment: I ran your code and each key was printed as packagename.TestClass@1, which means your hashCode, which always returns 1, is dfinitely used. What makes you thing String's hashCode was used?

Comment: No `String` involved in this code that works perfectly for what it does ;)

Comment: Put debug point on String hash code and tried debugging.My question is not well understood here i guess.I mean why is string class hashcode is being called when i have defined my own

Answer (score 2):

> Put debug point on String hash code and tried debugging. My question is not well understood here i guess.I mean why is string class hashcode is being called when i have defined my own

I tried your code and put a breakpoint on `String::hashCode`. The breakpoint was hit, but not by your code.

In the call stack I see that `String.hashCode()` is called by `Properties(HashTable<K,V>).get(Object)`, which is called by `Properties.getProperty(String)`, which is called by `System.getProperty(String)`. This is called even when I run a program with an empty `main()` method.

Your code uses your own `hashCode` method (which returns 1).

Comment: Eran, why is it calling String.hashcode() and why not the hashcode() of my  TestClass

Comment: @user3405305 I thought I was clear. It calls `String.hashCode()` regardless of your code (see the call stack). Your `HashMap<TestClass, Integer>` does use your `hashCode()` of `TestClass`.

Answer (score 0):

your `hashmap` will have everytime the same hashcode as you have overridden the hashcode method of object class,  so at one bucket many objects will be resided and You are overriding Object's class's `equals` method , not `String` class for more information [find this link which I had faced the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29362401/2749470)